# Program unexpected execution

Tags: python

I am trying to run below **python code**

```
list_name = []
dictionary = {'fname' : '' , 'lname' :''}
for i in range(0,2):
    dictionary['fname'] = i
    dictionary['lname'] = i
    print dictionary
    list_name.append(dictionary)
    #dictionary = {'fname' : '' , 'lname' :''}
print "List : ", list_name
```

**Output**

```
{'lname': 0, 'fname': 0}
{'lname': 1, 'fname': 1}
Array :  [{'lname': 2, 'fname': 2}, {'lname': 2, 'fname': 2}]
```

When I uncomment this line `dictionary = {'fname' : '' , 'lname' :''}` in above code
I get this

**Output**

```
{'lname': 0, 'fname': 0}
{'lname': 1, 'fname': 1}
Array :  [{'lname': 0, 'fname': 0}, {'lname': 1, 'fname': 1}]
```

I am not getting the default behavior of python...Please explain

Comment: The code appends **a same dictionary** twice.

Comment: @falsetru Why the same dictionary is appended twice that is my question. It should have been different as am I appending in a loop

Comment: The reference `dictionary` never changed. Try `print id(dictionary)` in the loop (with comment / uncomment)

Comment: Just move the line `dictionary = {'fname' : '' , 'lname' :''}` *inside* the `for` loop and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @falsetru +1 Thanks for the `id()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer thanks to @falsetru for his comment, when I `print id(dictionary)`
I get **same id printed** when I un comment `dictionary = {'fname' : '' , 'lname' :''}`
I get **different ids printed**.

```
list_name = []
dictionary = {'fname' : '' , 'lname' :''}
for i in range(0,2):
    dictionary['fname'] = i
    dictionary['lname'] = i
    print dictionary
    print id(dictionary)
    list_name.append(dictionary)
    #dictionary = {'fname' : '' , 'lname' :''}
print "List : ", list_name
```